ColorPicker localization change in WinUI 3
I have a question, is there any way to update ColorPicker xaml element in WinUI3 when there's runtime language change in application without restart?
I tried to change Language property in ColorPicker, but language of it hadn't changed a bit.

AFAIK, the built-in localization won't update those labels unless you restart the app. Instead, you can localize them by yourself:
private Dictionary<string, string> EnglishToSpanishDictionary { get; } = new()
{
    { "Red", "Rojo" },
    { "Green", "Verde" },
    { "Blue", "Azul" },
    { "Hue", "Matiz" },
    { "Saturation", "Saturación" },
    { "Value", "Valor" },
    { "Opacity", "Opacidad" },
};

private void ColorPicker_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is not ColorPicker colorPicker)
    {
        return;
    }

    LocalizeColorPicker(colorPicker, EnglishToSpanishDictionary);
}

private static void LocalizeColorPicker(ColorPicker colorPicker, Dictionary<string, string> dictionary)
{
    if (colorPicker.FindDescendants().OfType<TextBlock>() is not { } textBlocks)
    {
        return;
    }

    foreach (var textBlock in textBlocks)
    {
        if (dictionary.TryGetValue(textBlock.Text, out string? localizedString) is false ||
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(localizedString) is true)
        {
            continue;
        }

        textBlock.Text = localizedString;
    }
}

The FindDescendants extension comes from the CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Extensions NuGet package.
Also, if you need runtime localization, check the WinUI3Localizer NuGet package. (I'm the author;))
